# Data driven Subscription

Tags: reporting-services, ssrs-2008-r2, subscription

[image]I have a report for which a Data Driven Subscription was created by someone else.
I am not able to understand things in  that.
In Step 4 where we are Specifying delivery extension settings for Report Server Email in this point we are setting vaues of To, Subject from Getting values from Database.
Can anybody explain me what is going on in this step. As m not receiving To and Subject from my query.
From where we are getting this

Comment: provide a screenshot of the step 3 and step 4 also.

Comment: I have updated my question

Comment: Are there a number of email recipients listed in the initial page of the subscription set up? If so then one of these may be the cause of your problem. If an email address mentioned in the "To" list no longer exists in your company's address book then the subscription will fail. We've worked around this flaw by setting up email Groups. The Group will never leave the company, so the subscription will always work!

Comment: What about Step 3 where you might find command or query to vary the delivery settings and report parameter values?

Comment: Mail is coming to the users, but from my own learning perspective I wanted to know that there is no as such query for the clients in TO list, then from where it is fetching the result

Comment: @Abhishek, in step3 we just have the name of stored procedure, nothing else

Comment: Check the Stored procedure code then it must be fetching the information, else you can paste the code here too.